# Am trying to filter record by card_type, created_at etc, it return success without the data, can someone help please

Tags: mysql, laravel

Filtering with laravel and sql.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = ( new Offer() )->newQuery();

    if ($request->has('card_type')) {
        $query->where(['card_type' => $request->card_type]);
    }

    if ($request->has('created_at')) {
        $query->where(['created_at' => $request->created_at]);
    }

    $data = $query->get();

    return $this->jsonResponse(HTTP_SUCCESS, 'Successfully retrieved', $data);
}
```

Comment: that's some really strict condition `$query->where(['created_at' => $request->created_at]);` only get offers created in that specific second. better just call it by id then ^^

Comment: If you send both `card_type` and `created_at` then maybe there would be no results in the database thus, an empty result will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you send one request card_type or created_at because If you send both created_at and card_type no results get from the database

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).